# Galaxy S I9000 does not boot at all

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

My Samsung Galaxy S I9000 does not boot at all, the screen does not come, no vibration, no backlight on the soft buttons. It's as if it was dead.

I reset the battery and hard reset. But nothing seems to work. Any way to get it working, other than heading to a service center?

It has Slimrom's Slimbean 4.1 in it, international version of Galaxy S.

Answer (score 0):

Can you boot into recovery mode (Vol Up + Home + Power button combo) or download mode (Vol Down + Home + Power button combo)? If not, have it checked by a service center.

Comment: I tried that, doesn't work. Not even the initial boot up screen (Galaxy S I9000) shows up. I guess service center is the option. Any other hard reset options?